# Fastcgi++: How to create 404 or 503 responses

Tags: c++, fastcgi, fastcgi++

Fastcgi++ is a library for easing the implementation of fastcgi servers in C++. And here is the very simple use case that I want to do: to check for the existence of a file, and if doesn't exist, to generate some error message. Here is the code, look for the question signs.

```
struct the_fastcgi_server_t: Fastcgipp::Request<char>
{

    bool response() 
    {
        using namespace Fastcgipp;

        Fastcgipp::Http::Environment<char> const &env =
            this->environment();
        // Can I resolve the file?
        std::string target_js;
        try {
            target_js = path_processor( env.scriptName );
        } catch ( file_not_found_exc_t const& e )
        {
            // TODO How do I set a standard 404 here???!!
            return true;
        }

        out << "Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

        // ... Here I fill the response.

        return true;
    }
};
```

Any ideas about how to set the response type?

Comment: Ask on the mailing list https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/fastcgipp-users

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is basically as here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160115021335/http://www.fastcgi.com/docs/faq.html#httpstatus

That is, use a fragment of code like this one

```
 out << "Status: 404 Not found\r\n\r\n";
```

in the response method. It is not standard http, but FastCGI is just a wrapper over CGI, and that's how [CGI does it](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-6.2.1).