# FCGI_SetExitStatus doesn't works

Tags: c++, fastcgi

I build FastCGI-server with "fcgi_stdio.h". All works fine, except one problem. I want to set up HTTP status of response. So I write, for example:

```
...
FCGI_SetExitStatus( 404 );
FCGI_Finish();
```

But response has status 200 (I see it in the Chrome, with Web Developer plugin).

What can I do?

Tested on Ubuntu Linux 12.04, Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FCGI_SetExitStatus()` does not set the `HTTP` status code; the exit code it sets only has application-level meaning.

You need to output an additional header like `Status: 404 Not Found`. See [this similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387122/fastcgi-how-to-create-404-or-503-responses) and the [FastCGI FAQ](http://www.fastcgi.com/docs/faq.html#httpstatus).